# Android mock gps; What setting can trigger this code to work?

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I created a gps based application which does not allow any gps mock providers.

It works well on most cases, but one of my user says that he keeps getting messages that he is using mock gps.

The code below is the suspicious part.

```
           if (!Settings.Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0")) {

                ErrorController.showMessage("MOCK LOCATION");
                mCallback.onFakeGps();
                turnGpsOff();
                return;
            }
```

I've got this code from some searching, but when testing it, I never got caught in this code. it was always 0.

I'm using galaxy s10e as my primary test device, and the user is using galaxy s7 edge, probobly android 7 or 8.

Where can I find the setting that can make the above code to work? Please help!

Comment: Are you getting location from Location listener.?

Comment: Yes I am. An old fashion LocationProvider stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
 As per your comment you can check whether the location you're getting is from
 mock or fake gps use below code snippet
 if(!location.isFromMockProvider())
 { 
   // Not a Fake or MockLocation
 }
```

Comment: This code is right below the code I've posted. This code works for devices that are using mock locations provided via 'mock location apps'. My question is not about this, but the option that triggers my code to go into the if clause.